# Как сделать чтобы при наведении на изображение скрытый блок отображался только поверх этого изображения?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
.recent {
    position: relative;
}

.info {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(248,229,20,.9);
}

.recent:hover ~ .info {
    display: block !important;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="recent" href=#>
                <img src="img/man_1.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="J D">
                </a>
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                </div>
                <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
                <p>Lead Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте всплывающее окно во внутрь ссылки, сделайте ее инлайн-блочной:

```css
.recent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(248, 229, 20, .9);
}

.recent:hover .info {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a class="recent" href=#>
      <img src="https://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/06/f0d0cc5ccc44314f370898fece025a32.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="J D">
      <div class="info d-none">
        <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
    <p>Lead Designer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если ответ вам помог, то отмечайте его ответом

Comment: Помогло только после того как убрал ~ из кода почему с ним не работало?

Comment: в моем примере тильды и не было

Comment: а в примере проблемного участка кода как раз используется тильда, а в вашем ответе ее уже нету чем она мешает так сильно?

Comment: её и не было - историю правок здесь можно легко увидеть. Это получается совершенно разные селекторы, используя тильду вы выбираете близлежащие родственные элементы, а без нее дочерние.